# Criar tabela apostila Java EE 7 Algaworks

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar o banco de dados do curso da apostila Java EE 7 com Jsf, Primefaces e CDI e não estou conseguindo.
Dá o erro abaixo:

```
set 17, 2017 8:24:22 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
set 17, 2017 8:24:22 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.3.Final}
set 17, 2017 8:24:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
set 17, 2017 8:24:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/financeiro]
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Base 'financeiro' inconnue
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
ERROR: HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Base 'financeiro' inconnue
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1769)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.algaworks.financeiro.util.CriaTabelas.main(CriaTabelas.java:7)

set 17, 2017 8:24:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Meu persintence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="FinanceiroPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/financeiro"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"
            value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

Minha classe CriaTabelas

```
package com.algaworks.financeiro.util;

import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class CriaTabelas {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FinanceiroPU");
    }
}
```

Comment: Há usuários que acham que os demais usuários do StackOverflow têm poderes mágicos telepáticos de clarividência e são capazes de adivinhar com exatidão o que é que está acontecendo no ambiente de quem pergunta. Acreditam que esses seres StackOverflownianos dotados de superpoderes podem adivinhar qual é o código, a mensagem de erro, a configuração do sistema e todas as outras informações necessárias sem precisar ver nada sobre isso e ainda são capazes de descobrir o que há de errado nisso tudo. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-nÃo-fazer-perguntas/5484#5484

Comment: Verifique se você tem essa database criada e se o nome é o mesmo que vc colocou no persistence.xml.

Comment: Uma dúvida, o seu MySQL está rodando em qual porta?

Answer (score 0):

Existe um problema de conexão com a base `financeiro`. Para tentarmos resolver esse problema, siga os passos abaixo:

1. *Confira os dados de conexão passados por parâmetro. Notei que você  passou a senha como em branco. Caso realmente não tenha senha, coloque uma e teste novamente. De preferência faça um teste de conexão utilizando o MySql WorkBench*
2. Retire a as propriedades: `hibernate.dialect`, `hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql` elas são opcionais
3. *Adicione a propriedade: `javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source`*
4. *Baixe novamente as dependências do maven*

Abaixo coloco uma configuração do persistence.xml que funciona normalmente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="crudPU">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/crude-tarefa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata" /> 
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

Siga todos esses passos e você deve conseguir realizar a conexão.